# copy text between two strings in a file using bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a XML file. From that, I want to copy the text between two strings.

Sample line from XML file:

`some stuff.........<br/><br/><br/>http://example.com/copythislink.php<br/><br/>After you.........some more stuff`

I want to copy all the text between

```
<br/><br/><br/>
```

and

```
<br/><br/>After you
```

These two strings occur only once in the xml file.I tried using `sed`. But, it returns an error because of `<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed 's#.*<br/><br/><br/>\(.*\)<br/><br/>After you.*#\1#' yourfile.xml
```

**(OR)**

If you want to extract only the URL.

```
sed -n 's#.*<br/><br/><br/>\(.*\)<br/><br/>After you.*#\1#p' yourfile.xml
```

Comment: it outputs the file again but the link is indented to the margin

Answer (score 2):

Using gnu grep

```
grep -Po '(?<=<br/><br/><br/>)((?!<br/><br/>After you).)*' file
```

#### Explanation

- `(?<=<br/><br/><br/>)` is a positive look-behind assertion
- `(?!<br/><br/>After you)` is a negative look-behind assertion

Answer (score 0):

If your need was only to extract the URI, a simple `grep` would have been enough. For example, something like :

```
grep -o "http:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\.\/]*" test.xml
```

However, if you really want to catch the text (whatever the kind of content, even if it doesn't contain an URI) between these both strings, the solution of sat works well.